# How to create JTree iterating over elements

Tags: java, loops, jtree

I have to create `JTree` iterating values and putting the current value into the previous.

This is my code:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode ext = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();

while (token.hasMoreElements()) {

    String str = (String) token.nextElement();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode tmp = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(str);
    ext.add(tmp);
    ext = tmp;  

}
```

But in this way I get only the last element..

Comment: You are discarding the first element. You should store the first `DefaultMutableTreeNode` in another variable

Answer (score 0):

First, you create an instance of `DefaultMutableTreeNode`. Then, you replace this variable with other instances in your `while` loop. After that loop, your variable contains the last instance, not the first one.

To fix this, store the first created instance in another variable, like this:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(), ext = node;
// your while loop
```